# How to remove the left tab on iGoogle

Tags: igoogle

The iGoogle pages now have "tabs" on the left side. I only use one tab, ever, so I don't really have any use for them. Is there a way to minimize them so they don't take up a bunch of space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this doesn't seem possible via iGoogle's settings. A lot of people did not seem to like this decision when it was rolled out ([google discussion thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google_web_search_help-personalizing/browse_thread/thread/82d4291a61467316/8562ef72e2dca83f)) and has been asked quite a few times in support ([you'll find some suggestions on how to get around this here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Web%20Search/thread?tid=282be484bb212cb0&hl=en)). To summarize info that is in that thread, you will need to run some script/extension/addon to remove the tabs which are browser specific of course. For example,

If you are using IE7 with add-ons via [IE7Pro](http://www.ie7pro.com/): [Toggle iGoogle Tabs](http://www.iescripts.org/view-scripts-491p1.htm)
If you are using Firefox: [iGoogle Tab Remover](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10113/)
If you are using Google Chrome: [iGoogle tab remover for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dlibebadhejgpjggjfijjgnomljihpeb)

Other browsers? Not too sure of but other people can probably add to the list.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/26855) and [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ncindhlccodninkgiofmmjdidmcmllhd) available.

I've just tried the chrome extension and it does seem to work as advertised.